# Using ASP.NET MVC with Javascript Google Charts

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I wish to use [Google organisational chart](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart.html) within my ASP.NET MVC project. I am however finding it difficult to get my head around how this would fit into the MVC architecture.

The Javascript to generate the chart will be contained in the head of my file and as this data will reguarly change, it needs to dynamically be created. Can anyone give me any tips on where to begin with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx). Scott Gu talks about `Sections` in MVC 3. I've used this before to create a section in the `head` tag to place script block/styles that apply to only one page, this gives you the freedom to use page specific script/styles without make your DOM a jumbled mess.